# Can we use service instead of push notification in android?

Tags: android, service, push-notification

I want to implement push notification in android.
I have search for push notification and know that for push notification I have to use C2DM.
For use of C2DM I have to keep connection live from my device. I want to get a counter from website when a counter changed.For that I have made a service and I am starting that service in every 5 minutes interval time.
So is it proper way to start service at every 5 minutes or I have to use C2DM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was want to get counter from webservice and want to update in application when ever it changed for that I had write a service and its work to make connection to webservice and get a count.I am starting this service at every 10 or 15 minutes and after getting counter i am dismissing this service and schedule after next 10 minutes.It is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast receiver is opt for push notification .

[Look at here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Thanks for your interest but How Broadcast receiver can help me in Pushnotification i can't understand

Comment: Push notification can be achieved by Android Cloud to Device Messaging Framework ,Xtify service,MQTT service